# php discounts. for some reason the discount is always applied

Tags: php

In one file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['discount'])) {
    $discount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "discount");
    if (IsInjected($discount))
        $errors .= "\n Bad discount value!";
    if ($discount == "refund20") {
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $_SESSION["discount"] = $discount;
            $errors .= "A $20 discount has been added to your purchase";
        }
    } else if ($discount == "refund25") {
        if (empty($errors)) {
            $_SESSION["discount"] = $discount;
            $errors .= "A $25 discount has been added to your purchase";
        }
    }
    $errors .= "\n Invalid discount code!";
}

?>
```

In pay file

```
<?php

$discount = $_SESSION["discount"];

// discounts applied
if ($discount == "refund25") {
    $cost -= 25;
} else if ($discount == "refund20") {
    $cost -= 20;
} else {
    $cost -= 0;
}
?>


<p><span class='b'>Discount Code :</span> $discount</p>
```

the issue im having is creating a base case for the discount code for when someone doesn't have the key

Comment: What is the "key"?

Comment: In both page add `session_start();` on top og the page just after starting `<?php` and then check

Comment: ive got the session start, and i was tryingto make the key the session discount in the first file, but then in the pay, if i dont type anything into my discount bar on my website, it says the discount code matches and deducts the amount

Comment: follow up question, when i see what the $discount is in pay, it is always the code (what i called key earlier), how do i make a conditional statement that that makes it not save, so the code and the amount isnt applied at the end?

Comment: what does     $_SESSION["discount"] = $discount;
do? I am assuming it is assigning the value of the users input into it, but how do i get it not to do that if the $discount from above does not match the code that i want it to?